# Why a vector field isn't determined solely by its divergence

Tags: calculus, vectors, physics, divergence-operator, curl

I am an undergraduate physics student. I would prefer answers that share more information and clarification rather than try to be concise.

To my understanding, Helmholtz theorem tells us that a vector function can be decomposed into the sum of a gradient of a scalar and curl of a vector function. Thus, if you know the divergence of a vector function is non-zero and also that the curl of the same function is zero, you can say that the vector function is wholly determined by the non-zero quantity. This occurs in electrostatics with the vector function for electric field. I understand this decomposition, but I would like to gain a better intuition as to why both quantities (divergence and curl) are needed to determine the vector field.

Suppose we have a vector function ${\textbf{D}}$ with divergence given by $\nabla \cdot \textbf{D} = \rho_{f}$. Let's say its curl is non-zero: $\nabla \times \textbf{D} = \nabla \times \textbf{P} \not= \textbf{0}$. The symbols aren't important, but they represent electric displacement ($\textbf{D}$), polarization ($\textbf{P}$), and free charge density ($\rho_{f}$) from 4ed Griffith's *Introduction to Electrodynamics*.

Is it accurate to draw parallels between the relationship of the derivative and integral of a scalar function and the divergence and anti-divergence (if such thing exists) of a vector function?

For example, let $$y = 1$$ Then, $$\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$$ And, $$\int{\frac{dy}{dx}} = C$$ where C is a constant.

Obviously, in the scalar case the anti-derivative does not have/provide enough information for us to go back to the original function $y$. Is this what is happening in the vector function case as well?

It seems I might be conflating boundary conditions (which if provided in the scalar case would give us a unique answer) and something else. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, the divergence of a vector field is a DERIVATIVE.  Just as with the derivative of a number valued function, you lose a constant (vector field).

Comment: @user1046533 Let me know if this is not clarifying. We have the derivative and anti-derivative operators. I am supposing that there is a divergence (true) and an anti-divergence operator analogous in function to the anti-derivative operator. 

Given such a pair of operators exists, does the analysis I presented in the question on the scalar function 1 carry over to an analysis of some vector function.

Comment: If a vector field were determined purely by its divergence, the Maxwell equation $\nabla\cdot B = 0$ would be saying the magnetic field doesn't exist.

Comment: `multivariable-calculus` may be a more appropriate tag to use than `calculus`.

Comment: Fun fact: the divergence and curl of $F = (y+z,x+z,x+y)$ are 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\rbf{\mathbf{R}}$For simplicity consider a smooth function $f:\rbf\to\rbf$. Suppose $f'(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$. Then for any constant $C$, one also has $(f+C)'=g$. So the derivative $f'$ does not determine the function $f$ completely. On the other hand, the derivative determines the function "partially". If one knows that $f'=g'$, then one must have $f=g+C$ by the mean value theorem. One can replace the domain $\rbf$ of $f$ with any open interval.

<sup>["Divergence" is misread as "gradient" in this part.]

$\def\bg{\mathbf{g}}$Now let $f:\rbf^3\to\rbf$ be a scalar function and suppose $\nabla f(x)=\bg(x)$ for all $x$. Then $\nabla(f+C)=\bg$ for any constant $C$. So the gradient $\nabla f$ does not determine the function $f$ completely. On the other hand, if $\nabla p = \nabla q$ for two scalar functions $p$ and $q$, then similarly, $p=q+C$ for some constant $C$. The result holds if one replaces $\rbf^3$ with any nonempty connected open subset of $\rbf^3$.


In the scalar case, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, *an* antiderivative of the function $g$ is given by
$$
f(x)=\int_0^xg(t)\;dt\;.
$$
In the vector-valued function case, *an* "anti-gradient" of the vector field $\bg$, assuming that $\textrm{curl} (\bg)=0$, can be found as the [line integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Line_integral_of_a_vector_field)
$$
f(x,y,z)=\int_{(0,0,0)\rightsquigarrow(x,y,z)} \bg\cdot dr
$$
where $(0,0,0)\rightsquigarrow(x,y,z)$ denotes any path from $(0,0,0)$ to $(x,y,z)$.</sup>

---

[Added later.]

Let $\lambda:\rbf^3\to\rbf$ be a scalar field on $\rbf^3$ and $F:\rbf^3\to\rbf^3$ a vector field with
$$
\nabla F=\lambda\;.\tag{1}
$$
Then every vector field $F_1:=F+C$ for some constant $C$ satisfies (1). So divergence alone does not determine the vector field. This answers your question in the title.

A [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition#Fields_with_prescribed_divergence_and_curl) says that a vector field can be constructed with both a specified divergence and a specified curl:
$$
\nabla\cdot F=\lambda,\quad \nabla\times  F=q\tag{2}
$$
where $q$ is a given divergence-free vector field. But since (2) is still invariant up to a constant, $F$ is not determined uniquely even by its divergence *and* curl. One needs an additional "decay property" of $F$ for uniqueness. That property can be thought of as some "boundary condition" to the system in (2).

Comment: typo on "∇p=∇q  for two scalar functions p and p"

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure that this quite answers the question. I think it's my fault for not presenting the question clearly. To my understanding, the second part of your answer refers to a conservative vector field which has such path integrals. 

Maybe my question can be simplified to: Suppose you know the divergence of a vector function: $\nabla \cdot \textbf{D} = \lambda$ where $\lambda$ is some arbitrary quantity. Can the curl of this vector function $\nabla \times \textbf{D}$ be considered a boundary condition for solving for the vector function $\textbf{D}$?

Comment: If so, could you give a hint (not the answer) as to where the need for two boundary conditions comes from? I haven't taken differential equations yet, but I assume an interpretation can be drawn from there?

Comment: @SillyGoose: I somehow misread "divergence" as "gradient". Now the answer is edited.

Comment: If you know $\nabla\cdot D=\lambda$ alone, you would need two more "boundary conditions", counting the degrees of freedom informally. The curl can be regarded as one condition; but for uniqueness, you would need yet another one.